# Error when using LIMIT and OFFSET on a Sqlite Query

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I'm using the following query:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat: @"DELETE FROM CarrelloMese LIMIT -1 OFFSET %d",indexPath.row];
```

But using the method:

```
NSLog(@"ERRORE: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(MyDB));
```

on the console I see that there's an error, the error reported is this: `near "LIMIT": syntax error`

What's wrong about that query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` only with `SELECT` queries, not with `DELETE` queries.

Consider deleting your rows by rowid instead.

Comment: I already tried but I'm showing the data on a UITableView where the user can delete the rows, The problem is that there can be 2 products that are the same thing but with different rowId, so if the user deletes the first one with the query I don't get the result I expect. Ty anyways, I'll use a select to get the correct rowId and then delete by using it